# semver dependencies problem when trying to install angular cli

Tags: javascript, angular, command-line-interface

When I try to install angular cli on Windows these errors appear and I can't finish, I've tried everything, can anyone help me?

npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit No fix available for @angular/cli@*

up to date, audited 242 packages in 8s

36 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

## npm audit report

semver  <7.5.2
Severity: moderate
semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw
No fix available
node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/semver
@angular/cli  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
node_modules/@angular/cli

2 moderate severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

I already updated node to the latest version, I tried to install angular with the older version @angular/cli@16.1.4

Answer (score 0):

The [fix for this has been merged](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/25437) (bump of `semver` to 7.5.3) and will be released this week in the version `16.1.2` of the CLI.